# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version etc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a simple table having id(autoincrement) and name and i am trying to do a very simple insert query

```
if (connect != null) {
                query = new StringBuffer("");
                query.append("INSERT INTO ");
                query.append("GROUP( ");
                query.append("GROUP_NAME ");
                query.append(") values (");
                query.append("?)");
                System.out.println(query.toString());
                stmt = connect.prepareStatement(query.toString());
                int i = 0;
                stmt.setString(1, group.getGroupName());
                records = stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

but it gives me an exception with stacktrace:

> 2016-02-09T10:00:44.876+0500|Severe:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP(
>   GROUP_NAME ) values ('Hockey')' at line 1

I have searched about such problems but couldn't find a proper solution.

Comment: What does the `query.toString()` print out?

Comment: May be `GROUP` not allowed as table name.

Comment: yeah that's right , my bad -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) in MySQL.

> Most of the reserved words in the table are forbidden by standard SQL as column or table names (for example, GROUP).

Preferably, you wouldn't use reserved words as identifiers at all, for exactly this reason. If you absolutely must, then use backticks <kbd>`</kbd> to quote reserved words, as described in [Section 9.2.1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) of the MySQL Reference Manual.

Comment: Thank u sir , can't believe i didn't see that . Btw why can't i use a simple quote instead of backtick because i don't think it's on my keyboard.

Comment: [This answer on dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23132) suggests that there is a mode you can set to allow the use of ANSI SQL double-quotes (`"`) instead of the MySQL-specific backticks.

Comment: thnx :)
i'll look into it

Comment: You don't need the backtick if you don't use reserved words, so don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `GROUP` as a name in MySQL unless it's enclosed in backticks:

```
INSERT INTO `group` (GROUP_NAME) VALUES (?)
```

Comment: yup that's right :)
Thanks a lot . I would upvote ur answer but don't have enough points